# Translation tools

Tags: localisation

I am a translator and have been asked to translate the contents of a webshop.
Where can I find a system on how to translate a complete webshop created in Magento without having to open each and every item?
Can it be linked to a CAT-tool so that repeated words don't have to be translated umpteen times?
where can I find information on how it works?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Good question! Unfortunately there is no easy answer. With "inline translation" you can translate texts on site but that means you will have to open every page. Good news is that if a text occurs multiple times *within the same module* you only have to translate it once. A helpful tool to discover untranslated texts is this free extension: https://github.com/ericthehacker/magento-untranslatedstrings